# Can the absolute position cause an image to get bigger than it originally was?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get `#features` div to overlap part of `.title-image` using z-index. When I set `.title-image` position to absolute, the image gets bigger than what it was previously. My question is, if `.title-image` is contained in a div called `col-lg-6`with sizing dimensions already added to it, would the sizing be thrown out even though the image was contained in a div? I used another image as the `.title-image` so that you would see what I am experiencing. What am I doing wrong?

```css
#title {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: #fff;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  color: #8f8f8f;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15%;
}


/* Navigation Bar */

.navbar {
  padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 400;
}


/* Download Buttons */

.download-button {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}


/* Title Image */

.title-image {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
}

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.features-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.icon {
  color: #ef8172;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.icon:hover {
  color: #ff4c68;
}


/* Testimonial Section */

#testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;
}

.testimonial-image {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

#press {
  background-color: #ef8172;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.press-logo {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}

.carousel-item {
  padding: 7% 15%;
}


/* Pricing */

#pricing {
  padding: 100px;
}

.sign-up {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.pricing-column {
  padding: 3% 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;400;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Bootstrap script -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">TinDog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">

          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>




      <!-- Title -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark download-button"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-light download-button"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-image" src="https://img.favpng.com/18/8/0/iphone-6s-plus-iphone-6-plus-apple-iphone-6s-png-favpng-2qagf951EWF4xaNNGb9WBPdNZ.jpg" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="features-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Easy to use</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>

      </div>

      <div class="features-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>

      </div>

      <div class="features-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="icon fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>

      </div>

    </div>







  </section>


  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

    <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-pause="hover">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>

      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
    </div>





  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">

        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>Free</h2>
            <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
            <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="sign-up w-100 btn btn-lg btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4 col-md-6">

        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Labrador</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="sign-up w-100 btn btn-lg btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="pricing-column col-lg-4">
        <div class="card h-100">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h3>Mastiff</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
            <p>Pirority Listing</p>
            <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
            <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
            <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
            <button type="button" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>







  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the default behavior of the browser on `absolute` or `fixed` positioning. Although it's still inside the container `div`, the `width: 60%` on `.title-image` no longer affects it as it's unable to find any parent element with its position set to `relative` or `absolute`.

> Remember that these values will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element itself meaning it will be placed relative to the page itself.

> The trade-off (and most important thing to remember) about absolute
> positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of
> elements on the page. An element with this type of positioning is not
> affected by other elements and it doesn’t affect other elements. This
> is a serious thing to consider every time you use absolute
> positioning. Its overuse or improper use can limit the flexibility of
> your site.
>
> https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/#absolute

If what you want is to position the `.title-image` relative to it's parent `div` you must set its (the parent `div`) position to `relative` or `absolute`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/o9wjrcd7/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

just add

Position:relative;

to the parent of title-img.
you are following the course full-stack course of angilia.

I was also having the same doubt

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I wasted like a day trying to solve that issue on my own.
This problem is caused because of different version of bootstrap.

position: absolute; changes the size of the image depending on the size of its nearest ancestor, and its parent should have a position other than static.

You need to set the position of its parent to relative in order to solve this problem.

```html
<div class="title-image-div col-lg-6">
   <img class="title-image" src="https://img.favpng.com/18/8/0/iphone-6s-plus-iphone-6-plus-apple-iphone-6s-png-favpng-2qagf951EWF4xaNNGb9WBPdNZ.jpg" alt="iphone-mockup">
</div>

<style>
.title-image-div {
position: relative;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

However; if an absolute positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.
I think you could try to position it relative and also reduce the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <img class="title-image" src="https://img.favpng.com/18/8/0/iphone-6s-plus-iphone-6-plus-apple-iphone-6s-png-favpng-2qagf951EWF4xaNNGb9WBPdNZ.jpg" alt="iphone-mockup">
</div>
```

try adding inline style to the parent of **.title-image** (col-lg-6) so it looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" style="position: relative;">
   <img class="title-image" src="https://img.favpng.com/18/8/0/iphone-6s-plus-iphone-6-plus-apple-iphone-6s-png-favpng-2qagf951EWF4xaNNGb9WBPdNZ.jpg" alt="iphone-mockup">
</div>
```

The reason for this is, angela used Bootsrap 4 in her course which give **col-lg-6** default position's value of relative. meanwhile, in Bootstrap 5 **col-lg-6** has default position's value of static

CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Title Images */
.title-image-con {
   position: relative;
}

.title-image {
    width: 60%;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    position: absolute;

}

/* Features */
#features {
    padding: 7% 15%;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}




<div class="title-image-con col-lg-6">
    <img class="title-image rotate" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone- 
     mockup">
</div>
```

Comment: Please give more information, try answering the questions made on the topic: `Can the absolute position cause an image to get bigger than it originally was?`, `would the sizing be thrown out even though the image was contained in a div?`, `What am I doing wrong?`, don't simply write a code, give some explanations and answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding another class name to the  element and make the position relative on css works for me.

[css snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0cTY.png)